# How to use ActionBarActivity

Tags: android

I am new at working with android studio and I am using ANDROID 4.0.3 (IceCreamSandwich) and jdk 1.8.0_25 , I have imported android.R

When I type `ActionBarActivity` it appears to be crossed off and when I typed some methods like I got errors

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
```

Comment: First, do not import android.R.... Second, ActionBarActivity is deprecated, use AppCompatActivity.  All you need to do is include the app compat library. Then use Alt-Enter to import classes that haven't been imported yet.

Comment: i removed ActionBarActivity and replaced it with AppCompatActivity and i imported AppCompatActivity but i still can't use R in methods like R.layout.activity_main or R.id.action_settings . the R is colored in red meaning " cannot resolve symbol R"

Comment: Don't import any R, and it should work.